# opacity filter not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to html and css/jquery. still i managed to create a website on my own using chrome's inspect element and other sources. But, the opacity filter is not working in firefox (version of firefox im using is 20.0.1). 
For the section "myHobbie" all the images are using the opacity factor (`-webkit-filter:opacity = 50%`) but when it comes to firefox, i found that it does not support webkit.

Can anyone please give me any other alternative for this so that it works for both firefox and chrome? Also if possible, for IE too.

My website url is: `www.srikarshastry.com/index_vertical.html`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @ hotdog1987: Always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: This could help **@hotdog1987** `>>---->` http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you are doing wrong is

```
-webkit-filter:opacity=50%
```

I will only used in browsers with [webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webkit) engine like chrome safari etc [more details](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html).
In your case mozilla firefox is using a different engine which is [gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29). For gecko you need to set opacity as

```
-moz-opacity:0.5;
```

OR

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

The transparency setting for all the browsers are given below.

```
.transparent {

    /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:0.5;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

More details you can refer [this link](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

Comment: i'm sorry but its still not working. here is the css:
    
    `#gallery {width: 1024px; height: 853px; margin: 25px auto;}

    #gallery a {display: block; float: left;
    margin:0px 15px 15px 15px; position: relative; padding: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}

    #gallery a img {display: block; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;}

    #gallery a img:hover{-webkit-filter: none; filter: none;}`

Comment: `#gallery a img.brightness:hover{-webkit-filter: brightness(0);
    brightness: 0; -moz-brightness:0;}
    
    .transparent{
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=50); -moz-opacity:0.5; opacity: 0.5;}`

Comment: now all i do is append class to my image links like this:

    `<div class=gallery>
<a class="fancybox-effects-d" rel="group" href="images/scrollingImages/sketches/02.jpg"><img src="images/scrollingImages/thumbnails//Sketches/02.jpg" alt="" class="transparent "/></a></div>`

the "fancybox-effects-d" is then run into jscript for ease-in and ease-out effects.

Answer (score 0):

for firefox, simply use:

```
opacity:0.5
```

> IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari use the property opacity for
>   transparency. The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0. A
>   lower value makes the element more transparent.
>
> IE8 and earlier use filter:alpha(opacity=x). The x can take a value
>   from 0 - 100. A lower value makes the element more transparent.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this opacity :0.5 for firefox

```
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Firefox */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  -webkit-opacity: 0.5; /* Chrome & Safari */

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. It worked finally. The hover effects were messed up. So, i made changes:

```
/*Hover effects*/
 #gallery a img:hover {
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 100;
}
/*Default state for brightness has to be specified specifically*/
#gallery a img.brightness:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(0);
brightness: 0;
    -moz-brightness:0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 100;
}
```