# mouseenter not firing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, mouseenter

My below jQuery is works as expected in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox. When I mouse over the .pin in Firebox nothing happens.(i.e. no opacity change...)

Advice appreciated!

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".pin", function() { 
  $(".map-box").css("opacity", 1);
})
  .on("click", ".map-box button", function() {
    $(".map-box").css("opacity", 0);
});
```

Comment: First rule out the possiblity that the callback does happen, but the CSS doesn't take effect. Never assume a callback isn't happening just because it isn't ostensibly happening.

Comment: this question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140123/opacity-filter-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opacity filter not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140123/opacity-filter-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Utkanos, I'm new to coding. How do I check to see if callback is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I looked at the post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140123/opacity-filter-not-working-in-firefox, and it didn't solve for my case. Any other thoughts?